# Configuring Default Route and Redirects in Angular Single Page Application

Tags: angular, routes, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a single-page application in Angular, where the default route is set to `DOMAIN/main`. My goal is to redirect every other URL to this default route, except for `DOMAIN/privacy`, which should open a different component related to privacy.

**Examples with desired and actual behavior:**

| URL | Expected Behaviour | Actual Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DOMAIN | DOMAIN/main | DOMAIN/main |
| DOMAIN/main | DOMAIN/main (just open MainPageComponent) | **DOMAIN/main/main** |
| DOMAIN/asdf/bcd | DOMAIN/main | **DOMAIN/asdf/bcd** (nothing happens except for some errors because it cannot find any `runtime.js` and similar files in there (obviously)) |
| DOMAIN/privacy | DOMAIN/privacy (just open ImprintComponent) | **DOMAIN/privacy/main** |

*(incorrect behavior is marked in bold.)*

I have gone through several posts and examples, but I'm still struggling to achieve the desired behavior. I don't fully understand how the redirects and paths work, and why the `**` wildcard doesn't match `/asdf/bcd` and redirect to `/main`.

**Here's the code I have tried so far:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "main",
    component: MainPageComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "privacy",
    pathMatch: "full",
    component: ImprintComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/main",
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/main",
  }
];
```

Inside `app.modules.ts`:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
```

### Questions

How do I get this working properly? I don't really understand those strange redirects / paths and also don't get why `**`i.e., doesnt match `/asdf/bcd` and consequently redirects to `/main`...

If you need further information, I will provide them as soon as possible. Thanks! :)

Comment: Removing pathMatch: "full" on main and privacy should do it?

Comment: Sadly nothing changes when I remove the "full" from `path: main` and `path: privacy`-Part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, I finally was able to solve this. As I have already suspected, the routing itself wasn't the problem. For building the Angular-Project, so that I can use it on a live sever, I added `"baseHref": ""` to `anglar.json`

So it **now works** by simpliy removing `"baseHref": ""` or changing ig to `"baseHref": "/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `pathMatch: 'full'` on main and save it on privacy. Also, you no need '**'

it should look like:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "main",
  component: MainPageComponent,
},
{
  path: "privacy",
  component: ImprintComponent,
  pathMatch: "full"
},
{
  path: "",
  redirectTo: "/main",
  pathMatch: "full",
}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Well, I do need the "**", if I want to redirect all "false" URLs to `/main`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this below. Instead of redirecting you can gan give the component itself. Also, remove the *pathMatch* param from configuration other than "".

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "main",
  component: MainPageComponent,
},
{
  path: "privacy",
  component: ImprintComponent
},
{
  path: "",
  component: MainPageComponent,
  pathMatch: "full",
},
{
  path: "**",
  component: MainPageComponent,
}]
```

Comment: While this solution works with a freshly created angular project, it doesn't work with mine. Thus I would guess, that I've messed up something else (because the routing still looks pretty similar to the one described in the original post)... I'll search for it :D

Comment: Sure, It might be some other configuration issue. Actually, your solution should also work. I have tried that. It worked pretty well.

Comment: Yeah, as I've already posted, I finally was able to work it out. Man, this cost me days of trouble xD